# VBA code can't access to DLL in System32

Tags: windows, vba, windows-7

My VBA code can't access to my DLL in the C:\Windows\System32 folder on Windows 7 64bit and Word 2010 32bit.

```
Private Declare Function my_func Lib "mydll.dll" (ByVal param As String) As Long

Public Sub MyFuncTest
  n = my_func("a")
End
```

I copied mydll.dll into C:\Windows\System32 and called MyFuncTest but got an error message like "Error 53: 'mydll.dll' not found".

However, I changed the declaration in code to:

```
Private Declare Function my_func Lib "C:\Users\myname\Documents\mydll.dll" (ByVal param As String) As Long
```

then I copied mydll.dll into C:\Users\myname\Documents, my account's Documents folder, and MyFuncTest successfully executed.

Changing "mydll.dll" to "C:\Windows\System32\mydll.dll" in the declaration did not work. And I tried accessing C:\Windows\System32\mydll.dll with FileSystemObject#FileExists method on the same VBA environment, but it returned False (not found).

There was no problem on Windows XP and Word 2003.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Here's a similar issue with the same root cause. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886297/whats-special-about-c-windows-system32-in-the-path

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a 32 bit DLL and a 32 bit process running in the WOW64 emulator on 64 bit Windows. [File redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187%28VS.85%29.aspx) is in play and so when a 32 bit process looks in `system32` it is actually redirected to the 32 bit system directory `SysWOW64`.

The simple and quick solution is to move the DLL to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`. However, as Cody Gray points out in a comment, it is not recommended for you to place application DLLs in the system directory. Normal practice is to place the DLLs in your application folder in the program files directory and make sure that folder is in the DLL search path when the DLL needs to be loaded.

Comment: Hmm, you beat me to answering this one. But I very much disagree with the recommendation to place DLLs in Windows system directories. You shouldn't be messing with those directories at all.

Comment: +1 for the **don't put files in the system folder** bit, as well as the WOW64 gubbins

Comment: Sorry, I haven't replied for a long time. Finally, I decided not to put dlls into system directories but my application's local directory. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like UAC is the problem. Try running the VBA script as Administrator. It may help you.

Comment: What makes you think UAC is the problem here?

Comment: Unlikely that UAC would prevent the script from calling a DLL. File system redirection is the problem, he's trying to call it from a 32-bit process.

Comment: I thought it may be because UAC blocking the script accessing the System directory.

Comment: If UAC stopped programs from loading DLLs in system directories, then everything would stop working!

Answer (score 0):

A recent developer suggested the following fix which allowed a 32bit .dll to be registered on a 64 bit machine

1) Open a DOS command window.

2) Navigate to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727

3) Enter the following and press enter. 
regasm /codebase "C:\Users\myname\Documents\mydll.dll"

Answer (score 0):

I have had exactly the same problem yesterday. The program run on my machine, but not on others.
In fact, the message fron Excel is wrong. He obviously find lhe dll file, but this dll is calling orher dll, missing in the system : `MSVCR100D.dll` and `NTDLL.dll.`
I found that by using Dependency Walker free software, able to examine which dll are call by a dll.