# What's special about "c:\windows\system32" in the %PATH%?

Tags: windows, dll, path, environment-variables, system32

As I remembered, when Windows looks for a DLL, it will check each of the directy in the `%PATH%` environment variable.

My %PATH% environment variable has a list of paths, which include the `c:\windows\system32`. I have a test application which depends on a DLL. I tried putting my DLL into each of the entry of `%PATH%`. It seems all entries work except the `c:\windows\system32`.

What's special about it?

Comment: My initial thought is permissions.

Comment: @Donald.Record yes, I thought about that,too. But even the `c:\windows` entry works. And I am running as admin.

Comment: Is the app x86 or x64? (also language your using?)

Comment: What version of Windows?  Also what do you mean that it doesn't work so far as what behavior you are seeing and what behavior you expect?

Comment: @RichardChambers I am using `Windows 7 SP1 Build 7601`.  I expect that if I put the DLL in either entry of the %PATH% environment variable, it should be located. But it turns out putting it in system32 folder cannot be found. Although `system32` folder IS included in the %PATH%.

Comment: @AustinFrench It's x86. I am sure.

Comment: Austin has spotted the problem.  32-bit applications that read from the system32 folder are redirected to the syswow64 folder.  If you put the DLL in syswow64 it will work.

Comment: Thanks Austin and Harry, redirection to syswow64 is the root cause. If you post it as answer. I will mark it.